# Getting a BITMAP dirrectly from a already installed windows raster (bitmap) font

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, bitmap

i know this seems to be a weird question, and it is! But taking advantage of the already installed fixed-width fonts of windows (ex: Fixedsys) i would save a lot of size (since i want to make the final EXE as small as possible)

Whats the best way to get the BITMAP (or the bits array) from an existent (already installed) raster/bitmap font on windows? Or theres **no way** to do it and i have to make a bmp file with all the letters and load as an resource?

And yes, i am trying making small executables as 16kbs, size counts A LOT! 
Thanks for your attention, i hope i explained it right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible: Create a DC, attach your bitmap and the font, render the font into the bitmap, detach and destroy the DC. You are left with a bitmap containing the letters you drawn with the font.

I assume you are familiar with GDI to accomplish the above. If not, find a good tutorial on GDI.

Comment: Thats a good idea! And yes, i guess i have an idea about how to do it now! Thanks! :D